# How to generate byte arrays for sending data over a network in Java

Tags: java, network-programming

I am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL server (implementing the wire protocol) but I can't figure out how to dynamically generate message frames of byte arrays. For example, in the following code I'm doing a lot of `System.arraycopy` calls to push all the generated bytes into a single byte array and it seems like there has to be a better way.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;


public class Connection {

    public void connect(String hostName, int port) {
        try {
            Socket dbSocket = new Socket(hostName, port);
            DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(dbSocket.getOutputStream());

            byte[] message = buildStartupMessage("sa");
            dOut.write(message);

            DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(dbSocket.getInputStream());
            byte bytes;
            while((bytes = dIn.readByte()) != 0) {
                System.out.println(bytes);
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Got an exception");
        }
    }

    public byte[] buildStartupMessage(String username) {
        // Postgres startup message format:
        // 32 bit length
        // 32 bit protocol
        // string name
        // null byte
        // string value
        // null byte
        byte nullbyte = 0;
        byte[] valbytes = username.getBytes();

        byte[] namebytes = "user".getBytes();

        System.out.println("number of bytes for sa is: " + valbytes.length);

        int length = 4 + 4 + valbytes.length + namebytes.length + 2;
        byte[] lengthbytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(length).array();
        byte[] protocolbytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(3).array();


        byte[] startupmessage = new byte[length];
        int currIndex = 0;
        System.arraycopy(lengthbytes, 0, startupmessage, currIndex, lengthbytes.length);
        currIndex += lengthbytes.length;
        System.arraycopy(protocolbytes, 0, startupmessage, currIndex, protocolbytes.length);
        currIndex += protocolbytes.length;
        System.arraycopy(namebytes, 0, startupmessage, currIndex, namebytes.length);
        currIndex += namebytes.length;
        startupmessage[currIndex] = nullbyte;
        currIndex++;
        System.arraycopy(valbytes, 0, startupmessage, currIndex, valbytes.length);
        currIndex += valbytes.length;
        startupmessage[currIndex] = nullbyte;

        return startupmessage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = new Connection();
        conn.connect("localhost", 5432);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can write the arrays to the stream directly instead of merging them into a single array.

Comment: You can also use a ByteArrayOutputStream and wrap it in a DataOutputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Don't. Use the primitives of `DataOutputStream` to write what you want directly. For example:

```
dos.writeInt(length); // total length
dos.writeInt(3); // protocol
dos.writeBytes("user");
dos.writeByte(0); // null terminator
dos.writeBytes(username); // username
dos.writeByte(0); // null terminator
```

... and the converse when reading via the `DataInputStream`, according to the protocol. Put buffered streams under the data streams to save system calls.

BUT ... The real question here is 'why'? You should certainly be using a PostgresSQL JDBC driver to talk to the server, rather than trying to roll the entire protocol yourself. It's already done for you, by the vendor. Don't do this.

NB When you get an exception, don't print out `Got an exception.` It is asinine. Print the *exception.*

Comment: It's just a learning exercise for me, don't worry - this isn't for production!

Comment: I **strongly** suggest you try something easier.

Comment: Any reason why? And do you have an alternate suggestion?

Comment: Because you're trying something rather difficult that you don't need to do and don't know how to do? *And* because you migh break the database.  There are any number of easy protocols you could implement. I would do both ends of a simple type-length-value protocol.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but do you have an example of a simple type-length-value protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public byte[] buildStartupMessage(String username) {
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
    b   .putInt(0)                  // length (dummy)
        .putInt(3)                  // protocol
        .put("user".getBytes())     // name
        .put((byte)0)               // null byte
        .put(username.getBytes())   // val
        .put((byte)0);              // null byte

    int length = b.position();
    b.rewind();
    b.putInt(length);               // length (actual)

    byte[] r = new byte[length];
    b.rewind();
    b.get(r, 0, length);            // copy to byte array
    return r;
}
```